# 960gs Sass arguments

Tags: sass, 960.gs

I'm currently in the process of learning 960gs using sass / compass, but I'm confused as to what the "$n" is in the following code and how to use the arguments.

```
$ninesixty-gutter-width: 20px !default

$ninesixty-grid-width: 960px !default

$ninesixty-columns: 12 !default

$ninesixty-class-separator: "_" !default

=grid-container
  margin-left: auto
  margin-right: auto
  width: $ninesixty-grid-width

=grid-width($n, $cols: $ninesixty-columns, $gutter-width: $ninesixty-gutter-width)
  width: $ninesixty-grid-width / $cols * $n - $gutter-width
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://github.com/nextmat/compass-960-plugin) for that plugin...

"`N` is the number of grid columns to span as in `grid_N` or `push_N` with the original 960 Grid System framework."

Comment: I've realize that part, but when I try to @include it, it outputs an error stating that $n is an undefined variable.  What do I put in reference to $n?

Comment: To assist further I would need to see what you've tried in more detail - $n is simply an integer from 1-12, if that's what you're passing as a value the error is likely triggered elsewhere